# Indesign 2020 taking over my computer

Tags: file-permissions, adobe-indesign, adobe-creative-cloud, unwanted-application

Yesterday I was attempting to install an update on a non-related program. After fighting for days, it was finally installing. Right then, Creative Cloud decided to install some sort of update. I cancelled the CC download. Later I opened a book file with about 106 documents in it; it opened into 2020, without my permission, even though the test week was long gone. I got out as soon as possible.

Now, none of my indesign files created with cs6 will open when clicked on. They all lead to photshop cs6 or indesign 2020. So, I tried to use the open with function, hoping to tell it to open with indesign cs6. cs6 does not show in the choices. Even when I choose the look for more options, cs6 does not show. Only indesign 2020 shows. All my indesign files are now labeled for 2020 or photoshop. Its like 2020 took over my whole computer. I wish I never decided to try it for a week. I tried to delete it and get a notice saying 2020 is not on my system. It also says I do not have creative cloud either. However, when I open cs6 from its desktop shortcut, it opens and I can open indesign files that way.  I use Windows 10.

Should I reinstall CC, then try to delte indesign 2020?  Would doing that delete any of my files?

How do I get my indesign files back to normal and end this nightmare? I am talking many many hundreds of files. I was told that a test version of indesign 2020 would run alongside cs6 and not cause problems. Wrong. Thanks for your time and consideration.

Comment: Why don't you just set the default program for the file extension?

Comment: Same as the now-closed question on graphics, you need to tell us what OS you're on. Generally the Adobe apps come with specific uninstallers, you don't just delete them like regular apps. Your OS still has them registered [by definition] so you didn't uninstall properly. & as before "run alongside" is what they do, but which has priority is assigned by your OS.

Comment: windows 10.  I have tried to change the extension, but indesigh cs6 is no longer listed.

Comment: Why are you changing the extension? That will remain the same. You need to correctly remove all trace of CC2020, then change the association in Default Programs.

Comment: I cannot remove indesign 2020.  When I try I get a message saying it is already removed or does not exist.  I am not trying to change the extention, just the attribute.  My only options are photoshop cs6 and indesign 2020.  It is as if indesign cs6 does not exist in any choices.

Answer (score 1):

Long story short, I finall got it cleared up; I think.  Spent 8 hours either on hold or waiting for huge files to download.  I decided to call Adobe.  I had little hope from past experiences.  However, today, I actually got help.

The first tech I got did a screen share and bumbled about for almost two hours.  Then he disappeared.  Accomplished nothing.  I called again, after an hour and half I finally got a dud who knew his stuff.  I turns out they have a remove cc tool.  He sent it to my computer and deleted CC and indesign 2020 in a few minutes.  But, that was not enough.  Indesign cs6 was currupt.  So, he sent me to another person who would reninstall all of cs6.  I am in the country so my internet is slow.  Took about an hour and a half to download.  Lost that tech person.  Called again, waited 45 minutes and got someone who did the install.  I imagine the first dude may have messed something up, I will find out the hard way.

What I learned, when CC decides to download, just stand back and cover your eyes.  Worry about it when it's over.  Don't cancel it.

Try Adobe.  They really have a help service.

If you need to delete CC and the tech fumbles around, hang up and find one who knows about the CC cleaner app.  It works.

I sure hope the nightmare is over.

Thanks for all the help.

Suzanne

Comment: So… pretty much what I already said, except for your CS6 corruption, which may have been the first guy fumbling.